# Select Multiple Contact in android

Tags: android

i got phone book contacts to my application by using following code .but i want to select multiple contacts and upload those to DB ..is it possible?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  
                                        Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible.
I think you want to pick contacts information and then save it.
try this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

After retrieving contacts then write the code to store it in database

Comment: Ok Thanks. I store contacts in database.

Comment: Sounds good that you could.But why do you need to store it in database as it is already in android database.If you are trying to do something for backup then okay, otherwise think about it as you always get it from android whenever you need.